# Seleccionar y quitar selección en un div con jquery

Tags: jquery

Tengo varios divs, al hacer click en uno, le cambio el color al borde de ese div, pero deseo que al aplicarle el color a ese, los demás tengan el color cuando no están seleccionados.

En pocas palabras, deseo controlar que sólo uno de los divs pueda tener ese color de borde. Hasta ahorita tengo esto:

```
$('.div').click(function (e) {
    $(this).css("border-color", "blue");
});
```

Me aplica el color de borde al selecionado, pero si doy click a otro div también se le aplica el color y no me quita el color anterior (Múltiple selección).
También deseo quitar la selección al volver a dar click con el mouse.

Alguna idea?

(.div es una clase con propiedades y color de borde)

Comment: Podés probar poniendo en lugar de "(e)", "(event)" y en lugar de "$(this)", "$(event.target)". Saludos!

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es esta parte _pero si doy click a otro div también se le aplica el color y no me quita el color anterior (Múltiple selección)_ a qué te refieres?

Comment: Me imagino que lo que necesitas es que solo un div tenga el borde a la vez. La respuesta de Kete es la correcta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al hacer click en la capa, primero quita el estilo a todas las capas con clase `.div` y después aplícalo a la capa que te interesa:

```
$('.div').click(function (e) {
    $('.div').css("border-color", "transparent");
    $(this).css("border-color", "blue");
});
```

Comment: Me sirvió totalmente! Mil gracias